How to establish a predictive model for implementing or not implementing checks as an exposure factor?
I have observational data on a prospective cohort, including baseline measurements such as blood pressure and glucose, as well as data on cardiovascular disease incidence with 10-year follow-up. I want to design a study to determine the utility of fundus examination in preventive care.
Specifically, I'm considering whether to conduct fundus screenings for everyone or only for high-risk individuals (i.e., those with high blood pressure or high glucose). Screening everyone poses cost issues, so I want to demonstrate that screening only high-risk individuals can effectively predict future cardiovascular risk.
My data includes measurements such as blood pressure, glucose, and fundus examination results for all individuals. I'm using R software and I'm wondering how to model this scenario.
For instance, can interactive modeling like surv(py, cvd) ~ age + sex + fundus + highrisk + fundus:highrisk + (other_confunders) be effective? Here, 'highrisk' is a binary variable (0 or 1), with 1 indicating the need for fundus examination as determined by medical professionals due to high blood pressure or high glucose or other reasons. 0 means no fundus examination will be conducted (i.e., this group of individuals will not be examined in reality). Fundus is a categorical variable for the results of fundus examination.
Would this interactive modeling approach work, or is there a more appropriate method?
And, when I include a binary variable (highrisk) based on high blood pressure and high glucose in the model, can I also include the continuous values of blood pressure and glucose as part of the modeling? For example, surv(py, cvd) ~ age + sex + fundus + highrisk + fundus:highrisk + SBP + glucose. Would this lead to negative impacts on the model due to the relation between the binary variable (highrisk) and blood pressure and glucose?"
